# electron/muon: require not defined in renderer

Tags: node.js, electron, muon

I'm currently working on an IPFS/Ethereum dapp in Muon.
Because i need Metamask i started with this Boilerplate: https://github.com/SwapyNetwork/electron-metamask-boilerplate

Everything is working fine so far.
However i can not use require('anything') in the renderer process or in html script tags. (See below)

There seems to be a problem with the boilerplate code but i can't find it.
Or is node code in renderer not supported in Muon?

My only change in testing is setting node-integration explicitly to true and
inserting require('fs') in index.js. (i installed fs of course).

I tried many different solutions from stackoverflow and other sites but couldn't find a solution yet.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2VKp.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the muon's [github repo](https://github.com/brave/muon):

> Some of Muons goals include:
>
> 1. Use the Chromium source directly (eliminating electron's copy of chrome_src) with minor patches
>
>    - make integrating chrome components less painful
>    - faster and more streamlined end-to-end build process (see browser-laptop-bootstrap).
> 2. add support for Chrome extensions
> 3. add security focused features for the renderer:
>
>    - **remove node completely (from the renderer process)**
>    - full sandbox
>    - scriptable window.opener support

---

As you can see there, muon does not supports node code in the rendered. It is by design for security purpose. Muon may be great for certain applications, but I recommend switching on to electron if you really need to use *require* in the renderer.